# How many bytes does a char take up when stored in a string slice?

Tags: string, rust, character

I'm getting confused about strings/chars/slices in Rust. According to the documentation, a character is 4 bytes, however the program below shows a string of three characters uses 7 bytes in the slice. It seems like in the slice the characters are stored as efficiently as possible, so the regular 'A' is stored as 1 bytes, and the two Kanji characters are stored as 3 bytes each.

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("A漢字");
    let ss = &s[..];
    let sbytes = ss.len();
    let schars = s.chars().count();
    println!("{} is {} characters and {} bytes",ss,schars,sbytes);
}
```

```
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/test_string`
A漢字 is 3 characters and 7 bytes
```

Comment: That's because strings are encoded in UTF-8. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html Please read [chapter 8, section 2 of The Rust Programming language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-02-strings.html), which is fully dedicated to the subject.

Comment: I also recommend reading the [description of the UTF-8 encoding on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), which explains how different characters take different amounts of storage.

Answer (score 2):

I found that for a character c, you can know the bytes it will take up in the slice like this:

```
let b = c.len_utf8();
```

Answer (score 2):

Rust uses the UTF-8 encoding for strings. So, a `String` represents its text as a sequence of UTF-8 bytes, not as an array of characters. Here is a little demonstration:

```
assert_eq!("ಠ".len(), 3);
assert_eq!("ಠ".chars().count(), 1);
```